# Authentication with Prometheus Azure Monitor ConfigMap

Tags: azure-monitoring

Is it possible to add a token / credential for authenticated /metrics endpoints? There is not an option for it in the configmap template ->

https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-docker/blob/ci_feature_prod/Kubernetes/container-azm-ms-agentconfig.yaml

This can be done with prometheus itself easily. This Azure Monitoring feature seems kind of pointless if you can't use it to scrape authenticated metrics endpoints.

Thanks!